# Caliburn unable to load usercontrol as ActiveView inside Telerik's RadPane

Tags: wpf, telerik, caliburn.micro

I have recently moved ContentControl on the View(xaml) inside a telerik RadPane like so:

```
<telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
        <telerik:RadSplitContainer Visibility="{Binding UserControlVisible}">
            <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                <telerik:RadPane CanUserClose="False" Header="{Binding Operation}">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </telerik:RadPane>
            </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
        </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
    </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
```

Since, I have done this my UserControls are not injected as the Content inside ContentControl. I have tried to explicitly bind Content Property on ContentControl to ActiveItem but that says, unable to find the associated view.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Using code samples from the forums I put together a RadDockingManager for the RadPane. https://gist.github.com/1345512

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to add a datatemplate to the current content:

```
 <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
 </DataTemplate>
```

Where cal is:

```
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
```

and bind the active item explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Now it looks like

```
<telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>              
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer Visibility="{Binding UserControlVisible}">
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                    <telerik:RadPane CanUserClose="False" Header="{Binding Operation}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="{Binding ActiveItem}">
                            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </telerik:RadPane>
                </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
```